# Middleman server for ssh tunneling

Tags: networking, ssh, web-services

There is any online server to host a middleman server for ssh tunneling? I don't have another computer with public IP to do that.

My scenario: I have two PCs, each one in a different network and behind NAT (thus, without a Public IP). I need to use a middleman server to make the ssh between the computers possible and I would like to have this service 24/7 a week, if possible, that's why I'm looking for any provider of this kind of service.

*In both cases, I'm not authorized to do port forwarding on the routers.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like they may not want you using a SSH Tunnel proxy either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question as phrased is a product recommendation request (not suitable for SU).   Before its closed, I thought I might give you general advice - get a cheap VM - SSH requires very little resource and a low end VM is cheap - if you do a keyword search for "Low End Box" VM or similar you should be able to pick up something for less then $5.00 per month.

Of-course, if the host is compromised your SSH account can be as well - but this would be true, and indeed is a greater risk - if you could find an "ssh provider".

A nifty alternative might be to use VPN's to a mid point (if you can get a static IP address), or configure a VM for VPN use, and then VPN into that.  Set up correctly this could be a more secure solution then using some kind of SSH forwarding or middleman.